# Verticaly align image with text

Tags: css, reactjs

The image that I'm inserting is basically text so I want the image in the same line as of the text. The problem currently is that the image is going slightly higher than that of the text and isn't coming on the same line.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<Typography component="h1"  variant="h4">
        Welcome to <img width={200} src={logo}></img>
</Typography>
```

Here is the snapshot for further reference:

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do this, one is to add `span` tag around "Welcome to" like that `<span>Welcome to</span>` and add a `css` class for this span and for img to specify `vertical-align: middle;`

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `flex`, I would like to recommend to use `flex`

You can make it easy with it

`align-items: center`

```css
p{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<p>
  vertical aligned
  <img width="32" src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/cat-icon.png" />
</p>
<span>
  vertical not aligned
  <img width="32" src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/cat-icon.png" />
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work :)

Comment: Also, how to add extra space between the word 'to' and the image. The image currently is very close to the word 'to'.

Comment: @Amit Add `margin` on `<img />`

Comment: Yeah, yeah got it.